# R Removing duplicate entries in dataframe and keeping rows with fewer NAs and zeroes

Tags: r

I would like to deduplicate a data.frame I am generating from another
part of my codebase without the ability to know the order of the
columns and rows. The data.frame has some columns I want to compare
for duplication, here `A` and `B`, but I would like to then choose the
ones to keep from the rows that contain fewer NAs and zeros in other
columns in the dataframe, here `C`, `D` and `E`.

```
tc=
 'Id  B   A   C  D  E
   1  62  12  0  NA  NA
   2  12  62  1  1  1                  
   3  2   62  1  1  1
   4  62  12  1  1  1
   5  55  23  0  0  0      '

df =read.table(textConnection(tc),header=T)
```

I can use `duplicated`, but since I cannot control the order of the
columns and rows where my dataframe comes, I need a way to get the
unique values with fewer NAs and zeros.

This will work in the example, but won't if the incoming data.frame
has a different order:

```
df[!duplicated(data.frame(A=df$A,B=df$B),fromLast=TRUE),]
  Id  B  A C D E
2  2 12 62 1 1 1
3  3  2 62 1 1 1
4  4 62 12 1 1 1
5  5 55 23 0 0 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know the columns names, just don't know the order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach based on counting valid values and reordering the data frame.

First, count the `NA`s and `0`s in the columns `C`, `D`, and `E`.

```
rs <- rowSums(is.na(df[c("C", "D", "E")]) | !df[c("C", "D", "E")])
# [1] 3 0 0 0 3
```

Second, order the data frame by `A`, `B`, and the new variable:

```
df_ordered <- df[order(df$A, df$B, rs), ]
#   Id  B  A C  D  E
# 4  4 62 12 1  1  1
# 1  1 62 12 0 NA NA
# 5  5 55 23 0  0  0
# 3  3  2 62 1  1  1
# 2  2 12 62 1  1  1
```

Now, you can remove duplicated rows and keep the row with the highest number of valid values.

```
df_ordered[!duplicated(df_ordered[c("A", "B")]), ]
#   Id  B  A C D E
# 2  2 12 62 1 1 1
# 3  3  2 62 1 1 1
# 4  4 62 12 1 1 1
# 5  5 55 23 0 0 0
```

Comment: (+1) It is interesting that `!df[c("C", "D", "E")]` identifies only the zeroes, I find it hard to understand why. It seems that R converts everything that is `!=0` to `TRUE` and `==0` to `FALSE`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg a little RT*M will help: `?as.logical` will make it clear what gets treated as `TRUE` , and as always watch out for `NULL` and `NA` values.  e.g. `as.logical(NA)  #NA`

Comment: Just curious if there's a tidyverse update to this question?